# London: From Gatwick to the City with an Oyster Card

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, london, lgw, oyster-card

I am going to London in February and am not sure about all the uses of the Oyster Card. Can I use the Thameslink with an Oyster Card? Even in off-peak times such as 5am or 12 am?

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE :) Good question. Also, it happens to be one that has already been [asked and answered here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37598/can-i-get-from-gatwick-airport-to-london-by-oyster-card) :)

Comment: Why not use contactless ? One less card to carry.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for using the card are available fromthis page

https://tfl.gov.uk/campaign/rail-travel-outside-the-london-fare-zones#on-this-page-1

Basically, yes you can even though you are outside the normal area for Oyster services. Make sure you do not get the Gatwick Express but, as you say in your question, get Thameslink.

Check for possible strike action and other disruption on the National Rail site here

http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/service_disruptions/today.aspx

Comment: Yes, indeed [now you can](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/transport/you-can-now-travel-to-gatwick-airport-using-oyster-and-contactless-payment-cards-a3153621.html). Last November I was amazed that the long journey from Sidcup to Gatwick (changing trains at London Bridge and again at East Croydon) cost me only £2.60 using Oyster.